# Add line break to richt text content control

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml, word-contentcontrol

I have a function which add text to a rich content control in word. I have succeeded to get the content control by searching voor the tag. Then I add text with line breaks to the content control, but it does not accept the line breaks. It simply add the text on one line.

I would run the function (as in code below) several times, and add each new text on a new line in de content control.

I've tried several options as giving here on stackoverflow, but it still does not work. Can you please help me?

```
//Insert Text to manual.
public static WordprocessingDocument InsertText(this WordprocessingDocument doc, string contentControlTag, string text)
{
    SdtElement element = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<SdtElement>().FirstOrDefault(sdt => sdt.SdtProperties.GetFirstChild<Tag>()?.Val == contentControlTag);
    if (element == null)
        throw new ArgumentException($"ContentControlTag \"{contentControlTag}\" doesn't exist.");
    element.Descendants<Text>().First().Text = text;
    return doc;
}
```

Comment: `...but it still does not work` - This is not helpful. What does it actually do? It seems like you want to append rather than replace text, but it's unclear.

Comment: @Equalsk see my edit of the question

Answer (score 1):

Unless your string starts with a line-break or paragraph-break, whatever you add to the content control will simply be appended to the same line as whatever line already contains the last character. And, although you've described it as a 'rich content control', you might reconfirm that is the case - depending on how they're configured, plain text content controls can also accept paragraph breaks.